# How to update Source property of a frame by clicking only one button from user control?

Tags: wpf, binding, frame

I’d like to find out about how to update a source property by clicking only one "Next" button based on a click count and being able to load different pages into frame each time the button is clicked another time. Any advice is highly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Main Window Code:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Frame Content="Frame" Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Page1.xaml"/>
    <local:NavUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

User control that contains the button:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,20">
    <Button Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75"/>
    <Button Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" />
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a `PageViewModel` class that implements `NextPageCommand` and `PreviousPageCommand` commands, which raise (respectively) `UserNavigatedToNextPage` and `UserNavigatedToPreviousPage` events.  To make it simple, also have them expose `NextPage` and `PreviousPage` properties of type `PageViewModel`.  Create subclasses of `PageViewModel` for each page.

Create a view model class for the owning `UserControl` that exposes a `CurrentPage` property of type `PageViewModel`.  Create all of the `PageViewModel` objects and set `NextPage` and `PreviousPage` on each.  Add handlers for the navigation events on these object that look something like:

```
public void Page_UserNavigatedToNextPage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (sender == CurrentPage && CurrentPage.NextPage != null)
   {
      CurrentPage = CurrentPage.NextPage;
   }
}
```

Assuming that you've implemented property-change notification, now whenever the current page's `NextPageCommand` or `PreviousPageCommand` executes, the `CurrentPage` property will be updated and will be reflected in the UI.  If you've created a data template for each page view model type, all you need is

```
<ContentPresenter Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
```

in your user control and you're good to go.

If the Next/Previous buttons are in your control, and not in the page, then implement properties in the main view model that expose `CurrentPage.NextPageCommand` and `CurrentPage.PreviousPageCommand`, and bind the buttons to them.

Comment: How do NextPageCommand and PreviousPageCommand should look like? Lets say, I have 10 pages and only two buttons to navigate through. Should I do it with counter or there is another way? Code snippets will greatly help. Thank you again.

Comment: They're `RelayCommands`.  (Look up Josh Smith's Model/View/View Model article for a sample implementation of a `RelayCommand` class.)  All that the `NextPageCommand` actually does, when executed, is raise the `UserNavigatedToNextPage` event.  The user control's view model handles the event with the code I posted above.  The page view models are nodes in a (doubly) linked list.  Navigating from page to page is just traversing the list, so there's no need for a counter or an index, just `CurrentPage = CurrentPage.NextPage` or `CurrentPage = CurrentPage.PreviousPage`.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It is an interesting approach. I need to work on it.

Answer (score 1):

In your NavUserControl, I would wire up either events or commands (or both, perhaps) for the next and back buttons. Then you can access those from within the MainWindow and set the appropriate value into the Source property.

If you go the event route, attach onto the events and set the Source directly.

If you go the command route, setup a command in your viewmodel, bind it to the usercontrol, and bind the Source property to another value in your viewmodel.

**Edit:** Adding some code per the OP's request. Keep in mind, this is not intended to be best practices. Just some examples.

To go the ***event*** route should be the simplest. You already know how to do this, I'd imagine. Just add:

```
public event EventHandler BackClicked;
public event EventHandler NextClicked;

private void Back_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    BackClicked(sender, e);
}

private void Next_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NextClicked(sender, e);
}
```

events to your NavUserControl. Then change your XAML to:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,20">    
    <Button Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" Click="Back_Click" />    
    <Button Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" Click="Next_Click" />
</StackPanel>
```

And now in your MainWindow.xaml.cs file, add:

```
private void BackClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Uri source = // Whatever your business logic is to determine the previous page;
    _Frame.Source = source;
}

private void NextClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Uri source = // Whatever your business logic is to determine the next page;
    _Frame.Source = source;
}
```

and change the MainWindow XAML to be:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Frame x:Name="_Frame" Content="Frame" 
           Source="/WpfApplication1;component/Page1.xaml"/>
    <local:NavUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
                          BackClicked="BackClicked" NextClicked="NextClicked" />
</Grid>
```

Going the command route takes a little more architecting, but is a lot more clean. I'd recommend using your favorite MVVM toolkit. My favorite is [MVVMLight](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com), so that's what I'll use for this example.

Create a ViewModel class, something like this:

```
public class ViewModel : GalaSoft.MvvmLight.ViewModelBase
{
    private Uri _Source;
    public Uri Source
    {
        get { return _Source; }
        set
        {
            if (_Source != value)
            {
                _Source = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Source");
            }
        }
    }



    private GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand _BackCommand;
    public ICommand BackCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_BackCommand == null)
            {
                _BackCommand = new GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    Uri source = // Whatever your business logic is to determine the previous page
                    Source = source;
                });
            }
            return _BackCommand;
        }
    }

    private GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand _NextCommand;
    public ICommand NextCommand
    {
        get
        {
            if (_NextCommand == null)
            {
                _NextCommand = new GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand(() =>
                {
                    Uri source = // Whatever your business logic is to determine the next page
                    Source = source;
                });
            }
            return _NextCommand;
        }
    }
}
```

In your MainWindow.xaml.cs, create an instance of this class and set your DataContext property to that instance. Then setup your bindings:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">    
    <Frame Content="Frame" Source="{Binding Source}"/>    
    <local:NavUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</Grid>
```

and

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,20">    
    <Button Content="Back" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" Command="{Binding BackCommand}"/>    
    <Button Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="75" Command="{Binding NextCommand}" />
</StackPanel>
```

The binding example is pretty straight-forward MVVM-style WPF. I'd suggest you go that route and if you need more help, go read up on MVVM in WPF. Lots of resources out there in the form of tutorials and books. [Searching here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mvvm%20wpf) can help a lot as well.

**Edit again:**

Change your constructor to this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
    DataContext = new ViewModel();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It will be great to see that in a working sample.

Comment: which are you interested in? event-based or command-based? or both?

Comment: I'd like to learn both approaches. However, I don't want to bother you too much.

Comment: I added a lot of sample code. As I said in the edit, keep in mind that its not a best practices, just an example.

Comment: Tim, Thank you a lot for you well explained samples. It is a huge help for me in learning WPF. I tried event route and it works perfectly for me. I will try comands route too.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. I am trying to implement commands route. I debuged new solution and don't get any errors. However, something is not correct. The pages are never loaded into frame. I am wonderin if you wouldn't mind to look at my project and let me know what is missig. You can find the solution here: http://cid-0c29483cf3a6a14d.office.live.com/self.aspx/WPF%5E_Tests/FrameSourceGala.zip  Thank you again.

Comment: In addition, what would be a techinique to update source property for lets say 10 pages in this sample? Should have any counter or list?

Comment: I still have no luck with fixing the issue. I am wondering if you might have time to look at the project and let me know what is wrong. Yoy can find it here: http://cid-0c29483cf3a6a14d.office.live.com/self.aspx/WPF%5E_Tests/FrameSourceGala.zip. I debuged new solution with no errors recieved. However, the pages are never loaded into frame. I am stuck. Thank you nin advance.

Comment: You never set the DataContext of the MainWindow to be your ViewModel. So the ViewModel class you created (with the Back/Next buttons) is just sitting there not doing anything. I edited my post with the simplest fix for that.